# How would I go about creating a login form using a database for a check?

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a DB with a table called `person` with two rows called `personID` and `firstName`

Now, I have a form with 2 text boxes, asking for an ID and a first name.

Thing is, I have no idea how to go about checking the DB if the ID and the firstName are from the same record and taking you to another form called `admin` if the records match and if they don't just giving an error label.

I would love any help with this, thank you.

EDIT: This is the code as of now, getting the `connection already open, connection must be open` error

```
private void btnLoginScreen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        switch (dbAuth(txtAdminLogID.Text, txtAdminLogName.Text))
        {
            case true:
                //Open Admin form
                break;
            case false:
                //Show Errorlabel here
                break;
            case null:
                //An error occured while fetching data
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

public bool? dbAuth(string personID, string firstName)
{
    try
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM person";
        MySqlDataReader Reader;
        conn.Open();
        Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            if (Reader[0].ToString() == personID) //first check if the ID is equal
            {
                if (Reader[1].ToString() == firstName) //if ID is equal, check if firstName is equal
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is my connection string:

```
string connstring = "server=localhost;user Id=root;database=collegesystem;Convert Zero Datetime=True ";
        MySqlConnection conn;
```

Comment: juts make a sql query `select firstname from person where personID='<person_id_submitted_by_form>' and first_name='<first_name_submitted_by form>'` if query returns a record then then they are authorized..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how I would go(using MySQL-Connector):

```
public bool? Authenticate(string personID, string firstName)
{
    try
    {
        MySqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM yourTable";
        MySqlDataReader Reader;
        connection.Open();
        Reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            if (Reader[0].ToString() == personID) //first check if the ID is equal
            {
                if (Reader[1].ToString() == firstName) //if ID is equal, check if firstName is equal
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    return true; 
                }
            }
        }
        connection.Close();
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

In your form, where the login button is based use following code:

```
private void MySQL_Auth_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        switch (dbAuth.AuthenticatePlain(personID_textBox.Text, firstName_textBox.Text))
                {
                    case true:
                        //Open Admin form
                        break;
                    case false:
                        //Show Errorlabel here
                        break;
                    case null:
                        //An error occured while fetching data
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
         }
```

Comment: `dbAuth does not exit in current context`

Comment: Replace `dbAuth.AuthenticatePlain` with your authentacition method

Comment: okokok, got the error gone, but I tried testing it just then, and it gave me a message box saying `connection already open`, so I removed the `conn.Open` and then it said `connection must be valid`.. :S
EDIT: I posted the code above

Comment: Show me where you create your connectionstring

Comment: Ahh I think you forgot to assign a connection to your command. Replace `MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();` with `MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();`

Comment: Sure ;) You have to replace my comments inside the switch statement with your code

Comment: ...dammit, in my DB I only have one entry in the `person` table to test this, the ID being `1` and the name being `test` but my error message pops up saying wrong id or name...AAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRGGGH

EDIT: Would this have anything to do with the ID being an Int but the code says `ToString`?

Comment: Not really. The column `personID` in my DB is also an int and it's working fine. The problem is, that I don't know your whole code, and I am pretty sure that the error is caused by an error in your code

Comment: damn, well, I will try and figure it out, but this helped me a lot, thanks for this!

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you'll figure out what's causing the error. If not feel free to ask

Comment: Hey, I have a small improvement. Try to change `Reader[0]` to `Reader["personID"]`, do the same with `Reader[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

'This is the code you you have to write  behind the Login button

SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

```
            string query= "Select * from tblUsers Where (user_id=@id AND user_password=@pwd)";

            CN.Open();
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(txt, CN);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("id", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = this.txtUserID.Text;
            myCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("pwd", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = this.txtPassword.Text;
            SqlDataReader myReader;
            myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
            myReader.Read();
            if (myReader.HasRows)
            {

                CN.Close();
                AdminForm mf = new AdminForm();
                mf.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Invalid User Name or Password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            }
```

Comment: What is the `txt` in this line `SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(txt, CN);`

Comment: `txt` must be replaced with `query`

Comment: Yeh sorry, it is query, not txt.